# R: How to run some code on load of package?

Tags: r, r-package

I am learning to build a package for R. Now to set it up I need to run some code when the package is being loaded via `require(myPackage)`.

I read the documentation on `help(".onLoad")` that just made me really confused as there is no example. How do I actually use `.onLoad`?

Can someone please show me a simple example? For example I know `export(myfun)` in the NAMESPACE file will export `myfun` for use, what is the code that I need to run say `rnorm(10)` at package load?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

There is usually a "processing function" (traditionally called **zzz.R**) with
tasks to be performed when the package is loaded, such as loading libraries
and compiled code. For example you can create a zzz.R file where you create this function:

```
.onLoad <- function(libname, pkgname){
  x <- rnorm(10)   ## dummy example 
}
```

Comment: For example the dplyr package uses an .onLoad function visible in a [zzz.r file](https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/blob/bbcfe99e29fe737d456b0d7adc33d3c445a32d9d/R/zzz.r).

Comment: Has this functionality been removed? This wouldn't work for me but `assign('x', rnorm(1), envir = .GlobalEnv)` did work

Comment: @drj3122 No, the answer is simply wrong; this code *never* worked. But your code is also not correct, don’t write the data into the global environment. You want to write the data into the *package* environment. To do this you need to use `topenv()` instead of `.GlobalEnv`. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/67664852/1968.

Comment: @KonradRudolph What do you mean by the answer is wrong ?

Comment: @agstudy I mean that it doesn’t work: `<-` performs *local* assignment, which isn’t useful here (I realise this is a toy example, but one of the top use-cases of `.onLoad` is to set a package variable). Incidentally, using `<<-` wouldn’t fix this. See the linked answer for a proper fix.

Answer (score 1):

The R Packages ebook talks a bit more about using `.onLoad()` and `.onAttach()`: https://r-pkgs.org/r.html?q=onattach#when-you-do-need-side-effects

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31354000)

Comment: This link is now dead. Is there a new one?

Comment: https://r-pkgs.org/code.html#when-you-do-need-side-effects