# Automatic documentations of functions for Shiny app using RStudio

Tags: r, shiny, rstudio, roxygen2, testthat

I am developing a Shiny app at the moment and getting to a point with more functions than I expected. I plan to start automated testing with `testthat` and I would love to document my functions with `roxygen2`.

Since I am using RStudio, I started a new shiny app project. Now I am wondering, since I want the documentation and testing done, if I should instead start a *package* in RStudio to get all the `devtools` functions.

I am wondering, how to get the functions documented properly and like in the `build`, to test the examples. Plus using the `testthat` functions. How can I set up a project like this?

Comment: http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/ is a must; and imho packaging is a great way/idea to go one step further in R and programming as a whole.

Comment: So, than maybe a stupid question, how do you get the `Run App` button to start the shiny app, or do you just execute the `shinyApp()` via hand? :-)

Comment: would you like to lauch the app when you type `library(your_pkg)`? perhaps you can have a look [there](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20223601/r-how-to-run-some-code-on-load-of-package). but you may also want to have the possiblity to run the app by hand. if you're not happy with this function you can create an alias eg `fire <- function() shinyApp(ui, server)`

Comment: Thanks, I added the `fire` function already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I found now a workflow which works for me, I described this on a different question.

[developing shiny app as a package and deploying it to shiny server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37830819/developing-shiny-app-as-a-package-and-deploying-it-to-shiny-server)