# Include R6 class object in R package

Tags: r, package, r6

I am currently developing an R package and I want to include an object of class `R6`, which is basically an environment, so that users can easily use it (same way it works with datasets in a package).

I have an `R6ClassConstructor` Gridworld:

```
Gridworld <- R6::R6Class( ... )
```

Then I can create a new instance using `grid = Gridworld$new()`, which generates an R6 class. I then want to save this object `grid` in the package, so that a user can use it by just typing in `grid`.

I tried to save `grid` as an `.RData` object in the `/data` folder and document the R6 class in the `/R` folder:

```
#' Gridworld
#' @format R6 class
"grid"
```

but this causes an error in `devtools::document`: file 'grid.RData' has magic number 'X'

How can I include this `R6` class object in the package?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe it would be best to call `new` when the package is loaded. This way you will not have any troubles regarding reference semantics.

See the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20223601/r-how-to-run-some-code-on-load-of-package)

In your case, this would look like

```
# file R/zzz.R
.onLoad <- function(libname, pkgname){
  gridworldInstance <- Gridworld$new() 
}

# documentation
#' Instance of grid world
#' 
#' some description
#'
#' @name gridworldInstance
NULL
#' @export
```

Comment: Good idea! But I get the error message: "Error: object 'gridworldInstance' not found" when running `library("mypackage"); gridworldInstance`. If I use `<<-`  instead of `<-` `gridworldInstance` will exist in global workspace, but I don't like to change the global workspace on package load. Either way the help page is not accessible via `?gridworldInstance `.